# Region of Complex Plane When Given Modulus

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

If I have a complex number z, and I know that 1<|z-1|<2, and Im(z) < 0, I can figure out where the z-1 can lie on the complex plane. But to figure out where z can lie on the complex plane how would I go about doing this?

From 1<|z-1|<2 I can't add one all around cause it would be 2<|z-1|+1<3.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\vert z\vert<r$ is just a disk of radius $r$ centered at $0$. We can move the center of this disk to say, $a$ as $\vert  z-a \vert<r$. Thus your inequality, is one disk of radius 2, but you throw away a disk of radius 1. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Also, you condition Im$(z)<0$ just means that you have to intersect your resulting region with the lower half complex plane

Comment: Yeah I can take it from there, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You *do* add $1$ all around – to each point of the region where $z-1$ lies. This is a translation of the region by the vector (complex number) $1$, and so in this case the centre of the annulus that is the region should lie on $1$.

Adding the condition $\operatorname{Im} z<0$ means clipping to the lower half-plane.

Answer (score 0):

That region (I mean, $\{z\in\mathbb C\mid1<\lvert z-1\rvert<2\}$) is an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)), that is, the region between two conventric circles (centered at $0$). If you add the condition that $\operatorname{Im}z<0$, what you get is its bottom half.